# Clearing a drop down list in C#

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I truly do hate to ask such a crayon-question... I'm trying to clear, not remove a drop down combo list in VSC#. My ddl lets the user choose the payRate of an employee. I've researched everywhere, even here, and everything suggests using..

```
   cmboPayRate.Items.Clear();   .. or
   cmboPayRate.SelectedIndex = - 1;
```

I even threw in

```
cmboPayRate.SelectedItem = -1;
```

for safe measure. Nothing working. Again, I know this is easy(should be), but not working for me. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
-Matt.

Comment: Just remove every item... ASP.Net or WPF or Winforms?

Comment: What does "Nothings working" mean?

Comment: Is this windows forms or asp.net?

Comment: ..pardon my lack of an apostrophe, Jonathon..

Comment: ..this is a windows form application, @unlimit..

Answer (score 38):

try

```
DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
```

No hidden and clear the Drop Down List.

Answer (score 5):

you can do as below

```
while(cmboPayRate.Items.Count>0)
   cmboPayRate.Items.RemoveAt(0);
```

Comment: Understood & thank you. Next silly question: if I remove the items for clearing, are my 'collection fields' still there when entering for the next employee info?

Comment: This method will prevent the stackoverflow  error that RadDropDownList has when clearing items while in selected index change